# add all values to a list of list from a list

Tags: c#, list, linq, collections

I have a list of type class abc

```
public class abc
{
    public int count;
    public string country;
}
```

The list can have values like

> Count: 1 - country: US 
>  Count: 2 - country: US 
>  Count: 3 -
> country: IND 
>  Count: 4 - country: UK 
>  Count: 5 - country: UK

Now I want to put this list into a list of lists where it should be segregated based on countries.
My new list of lists should look like this

> Count: 1 - country: US  
>  Count: 2 - country: US
>
> Count: 3 - country: IND
>
> Count: 4 - country: UK 
>  Count: 5 - country: UK

The count can have any integer and the country can have any string.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: @TheGeneral its a example. I have further updated the question for it to be less confusing.

Comment: so dou want to have multiple lists?

Comment: I think you're slightly confused as to what a `List` actually is, your `Object` `abc` is not a list, it only has 2 properties, `count` and `country`, it has no items or a collection, making it not a `List`, if you wanted a list of: `Country` and a `Count` you could have a `List<string>` which has all the `Country` values added to it, then use the `GroupBy` function, which then would allow you to use the `country` as the Key and then get the total `Count` against that key / country

Comment: i want a list of lists so yeah multiple lists

Comment: @ConnorTJ i have mentioned in the first line it is a list of type abc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-5.0) and select afterwards each group into a separate list:

```
List<abc> mylist = new List<abc>()
{
    new abc{count = 1, country = "US"},
    new abc{count = 2, country = "US"},
    new abc{count = 3, country = "IND"},
    new abc{count = 4, country = "UK"},
    new abc{count = 5, country = "UK"},
};

List<List<abc>> result = mylist.GroupBy(x => x.country).Select(y => y.ToList()).ToList();
```

this way you get a list containing 3 other lists

Answer (score 1):

Implement it like this:

```
        List<abc> list = new List<abc>()
        {
            new abc() {country = "US", count = 1},
            new abc() {country = "US", count = 2},
            new abc() {country = "IND", count = 3},
            new abc() {country = "UK", count = 4},
            new abc() {country = "UK", count = 5}
        };
        
        Dictionary<string,List<abc>> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<abc>>();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            if(!dictionary.TryGetValue(item.country,out var l))
            {
                l = new List<abc>();
                dictionary.Add(item.country,l);
            }
            l.Add(item);
        }

        List<List<abc>> result = dictionary.Values.ToList();
```

Comment: dictionary.Values.ToList(); is this a valid function are you expecting it to be implemented ?

Comment: That is valid actually.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this.

```
List<abc> ls = new List<abc>();
ls.Add(new abc() { count = 1, country = "US" });
ls.Add(new abc() { count = 2, country = "US" });
ls.Add(new abc() { count = 3, country = "IND" });
ls.Add(new abc() { count = 4, country = "UK" });
ls.Add(new abc() { count = 5, country = "UK" });


List<List<abc>> listOfList = new List<List<abc>>();

foreach (var group in ls.GroupBy(x => x.country))
{
    List<abc> list = new List<abc>();
    foreach (var item in group)
    {
        list.Add(new abc() { count = item.count, country = item.country });
    }

    listOfList.Add(list);
}
```

**LINQ**

```
List<List<abc>> listOfList = new List<List<abc>>();
foreach (var (group, list) in from item in ls.GroupBy(x => x.country)
                            let temp = new List<abc>()
                            select (item, temp))
{
    foreach (var item2 in group)
    {
        list.Add(new abc() { count = item2.count, country = item2.country });
    }

    listOfList.Add(list);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like many already answered, you could group your list by the `countryString`. However I personally would prefer to add it into a dictionary, so the access would be much easier to understand.

```
List<abc> myList = new List<abc>()
{
    new abc{count = 1, country = "US"},
    new abc{count = 2, country = "US"},
    new abc{count = 3, country = "IND"},
    new abc{count = 4, country = "UK"},
    new abc{count = 5, country = "UK"},
};
```

You could as mentioned just group them:

```
var groupedLists = myList.GroupBy(x => x.country).Select(y => y.ToList()).ToList();
```

or you can make a dictionary out of it:

```
var myDictionary = myList.Select(item => item.country).Distinct().ToDictionary(country => country, country => myList.Where(item => item.country == country).ToList());
```

Now having the dictionary, you could access the specific list by the key (country). For example:

```
myDictionary["US"]; //would give you all items with the country "US"
```

It is up to you to chose whatever you would like to use. Just be aware that if you use the dictionary, you need to handle the possible `keyNotFoundException`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with Linq.

You can use `.GroupBy()` to create groupings based on a properties value - in this case the `Country`.

In this example the `.Select()` statement uses a named tuple to make the data a bit more readable.

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

var data = new List<Abc>()
{
    new()
    {
        Count = 1,
        Country = "UK"
    },
    new()
    {
        Count = 2,
        Country = "UK"
    },
    new()
    {
        Count = 3,
        Country = "US"
    }
};

var groupedData = data
    .GroupBy(x => x.Country)
    .Select(x => (Country: x.Key, Data: x.ToList()))
    .ToList();
```

---

A way to consume and use this list of lists would be like so:

```cs
foreach (var (country, groupData) in groupedData)
{
    var groupDataString = string.Join(" ", groupData.Select(x => x.Count));
    Console.WriteLine($"{country}: {groupDataString}");
}
```

---

Example output looks like:

```
UK: 1 2
US: 3
```